# Views implemented in Standard ML

Tags: types, sml, ml

Is there any implementation of ML that supports views as described by Okasaki here http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/chris-okasaki/views.pdf ?
Is there something similar in MosML/SMLNJ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a real-world implementation, but I once incorporated views into the [HaMLet](http://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/hamlet/#successor-ml) SML interpreter; specifically, a variant that targeted ["Successor ML"](http://www.successor-ml.org/) (link seems dead), an evolutionary extension of SML envisioned by the community at the time. As far as I know, there is no other implementation of views for SML.